# How to scale exponential data for a regression problem?

Tags: rnn, feature-engineering, normalization, feature-scaling

I understand that I should be scaling features between (0, 1) before feeding them into a neural network. However, what happens if future data could be larger than my current training data? For instance, if I am training a RNN on time-series data to perform demand forecasting, the product I am forecasting may be in a growth stage that will yield higher demand numbers in the future months than the past months. Is there a way to normalize data but still allow for larger values in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Instead of Min-Max scaling, that shrinks any distribution in the [0, 1] interval, you can Scale the variables (in statistics, they are called Z-scores). The formula is:

```
(x - mean(x)) / stdev(x)
```

This will zero-center the distribution, and scale all the variables to a standard deviation = 1.

I strongly prefer this technique to Min-Max Scaling, since the latter is too sensitive to outlier observations and generates problems unseen, out-of-scale datapoints.

Additionally, if your analysis allows for that, consider taking the log() of a data distribution that grows exponentially. That would coerce it to a more linear growth. (I'm not sure this is what you need, it's just a possibility.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Leevo. Is there a built-in function in SciKit-Learn that does this and also the transform of this with Numpy arrays in Python?

Comment: yes, you can use sklearn's `StandardScaler`. Call it like this: `from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler`. It works with numpy objects.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import yfinance as yf

# Define the ticker symbol
tickerSymbol = 'NVDA'

# Get data on this ticker
tickerData = yf.Ticker(tickerSymbol)

# Get the historical prices for this ticker
# '1m' interval for minute-by-minute data, adjust 'start' and 'end' as needed

tickerDf1 = tickerData.history(period='1d', start='2024-01-22', end='2024-01-26', interval='1M')
tickerDf2 = tickerData.history(period='1d', start='2024-01-29', end='2024-02-02', interval='1M')
tickerDf3 = tickerData.history(period='1d', start='2024-02-05', end='2024-02-09', interval='1M')
tickerDf4 = tickerData.history(period='1d', start='2024-02-12', end='2024-02-19', interval='1M')
```

In a recent personal experiment, I attempted to predict Nvidia stock prices using the last 2000 minutes of data, with a preceding 4000 minutes of data for training. The maximum closing price in the training data was lower than that in the test data. The neural network prediction followed the trend accurately but consistently forecasted values that were 0.04 less than the actual test data. By simply adding 0.04 to the predicted values, I was able to align the forecasts with the actual data, as shown in the provided image. Therefore, applying a simple linear regression to adjust the predictions within the test set could potentially match the actual values more closely.

I will add now (March 2nd 2024) to my original answer that I had used expanding window and Min-Max normalization successfully and published an article about it here [2](https://emad-ezzeldin4.medium.com/5-15-ror-from-backtesting-intraday-low-frequency-trading-on-10-fortune-500-stocks-last-week-93eae51b80c3?source=friends_link&sk=bd6fec022766657783b32135c2e34d0a).